# Secure Coding Practices for Developing Windows Phone Applications

Tags: windows-phone

Does anyone know a website which has a **security** checklist with regards to Windows Phone application development?  For instance, one of the recommendations may be to disable any unneeded privileges that the application may not need.

It is important that it is focused on the development of a secure windows phone application and NOT about the use of the phone in general.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

although it is retired content and not specific aimed at phone development it might still hold value in its core concepts.

The [Security Guidance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650760.aspx) of the [Patterns and Practices team](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921345.aspx)

An another option is the [SDL](http://www.microsoft.com/security/sdl/default.aspx) (Security Development Lifecycle)